# Entity Framework 1-to-1 relationship does not throw an exception when dependent entity is null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, one-to-one, fluent, ef-fluent-api

I'm trying to do a 1-to-1 mapping in Entity Framework and one example I found  [online was here, look for the 'Configure One-to-One relationship using Fluent API section'](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Most of the examples online is somewhat similar to the link, as well in some books that I've read while trying to implement this.

Here are my entities:

```
public class Student
{
    public Student() { }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public virtual StudentAddress Address { get; set; }

}

public class StudentAddress
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Zipcode { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

My data context that includes configuration using the fluent api:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Student { get; set; }

    // public DbSet<StudentAddress> Addresses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Configure StudentId as PK for StudentAddress
        modelBuilder.Entity<StudentAddress>()
            .HasKey(e => e.StudentId);

        // Configure StudentId as FK for StudentAddress
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                    .HasRequired(s => s.Address)
                    .WithRequiredPrincipal(ad => ad.Student);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var context = new DataContext())
        {
            var student = new Student { StudentName = "sample name" };
            context.Student.Add(student);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

In the console application, I expect it throw an exception since a `Student` must have a `StudentAddress` in order for it be saved, but when I ran the application and checked the database the student entry actually got saved. I might be missing something under the hood, though if I try adding the `[Required]` attribute on top of the `StudentAddress` property of the `Student` class, it throws an exception if I don't supply a `StudentAddress` for a `Student` Entity.

Comment: You have it backward.  A StudentAddress must have a student.  If a StudentAddress is required to create a student then you have a problem since StudentID is required to create a StudentAddress.  If both have to be populated and the relation is 1 to 1 then it should probably just be a single table.  In reality any kind of person/address relationship should probably be a 1 to many relationship since there are lots of people with more than 1 address.

Comment: Looks like the validation cannot be configured with Fluent API.

Comment: @DavidCram no, what I'm trying to do is have both ends required...meaning you cannot insert a Student without an address or vice-versa(though it is only in EF, because you cannot actually do that in SQL) anyway, what should happen is that when once you call SaveChanges it will throw an exception?

Comment: @IvanStoev you think so? have you tried doing the same in the past? hmmm...but that would be weird because I think most of us would expect that fluent api and data annotation should at least work the same or...the fluent api should be more powerful/flexible than data annotations. :)

Comment: I have, but just for testing purposes and haven't noticed that behavior. The configuration is ok - tables, columns, keys. But no validation. Btw, technically speaking, in databases there is no way to enforce 1-1, it's always 1-0..1, so this is EF attempt to logically enforce such constraint. Anyway, EF already has inconsistencies between data annotations and Fluent configuration, so this most probably is yet another one :)

Comment: @Ivan Stoev well yeah, that's for sure. thanks for the time man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I filed a bug to the EF team and here's the explanation why it behaves that way.

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/66#issuecomment-248073084

From Arthur Vickers (member of the EF dev team):

> EF will always let you insert a new principal (Student in your model) without any dependents regardless of whether the relationship is required or not. A required relationship means that a dependent (Address in your model) cannot be inserted without a corresponding principal. I realize that the way relationships are modeled in EF6 implies something different, but the decision to describe relationships in this way and then behave like this was made many years ago and we cannot change it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the declaration for the principal end of the relationship. In my experience, that is only needed if you are using annotation/attributes to create 1-1 relationships:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
    .HasRequired(s => s.Address);
```

Comment: my point exactly...it should be 1-1 so meaning you cannot save either entity without the other.(at least in Entity Framework when you call SaveChanges)

Comment: I expect it to throw an exception...it would if add a required attribute on both the navigation property of the entities. hmmmmm :)

Comment: As it stands, the above change creates a foreign key constraint violation, and therefore throws an exception when you try to add a Student without a StudentAddress.

Since you have the DBSet commented out for Addresses, you are unable to add a StudentAddress without creating a Student and adding the StudentAddress to the new Student before saving. Can you explain how this doesn't fulfill your needs? (This, by the way, doesn't use any annotations, as you requested.)

Comment: If you were planning on uncommenting the StudentAddresses DBSet, then I think you've found a bug, as the others have mentioned. I've checked in 6.1.1 - 6.1.3 and none of those versions work as intended. You may be forced to used annotations if you want this to work. Sorry :(

Comment: Yes, I do plan on uncommenting that one actually. I just tried commenting it and see how it affects before I posted this question here, anyways thanks for the time man! :)

Answer (score 0):

In one-to-one relation one end must be principal and second end must be dependent. Principal end is the one which will be inserted first and which can exist without the dependent one. Dependent end is the one which must be inserted after the principal because it has foreign key to the principal.

So try remove this:

```
.WithRequiredPrincipal(ad => ad.Student);
```

for

```
.WithRequiredDependent(ad => ad.Student);
```

or you can remove that row or use  `[Required]` data annotation on the property ...

Comment: well...the goal is to actually achieved it without using data annotations. again...I expect my code to throw an exception since both entity are required, so what should happen is that once you call SaveChanges the exception should be thrown similarly if I place a required attribute on both the navigation properties of my entities.

Comment: ok, did you try this: `modelBuilder.Entity<StudentAddress>()
            .HasKey(e => e.StudentId).HasRequired(s => s.Student);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                    .HasRequired(s => s.Address);`

Comment: that would produce an that states it could not determine the principal association between the entities.